# SAGA doesn't show up under providers in QGIS

Tags: qgis, saga

I want to use the SAGA processing tools, but it doesn't show up in the toolbox and when I go to processing > options > providers it doesn't show up. I have downloaded SAGA. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you also installed it? Have you tried reinstalling QGIS? Which QGIS version are you working with?

Comment: Have you activated SAGA GIS provider in the plugins dialog? Check the box next to it. See: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBgwz.png

Comment: @Babel I cannot open the plugins dialog for some reason. I cannot click on it

Comment: Than this is a completely different question. You should ask a new question for that.